How to reach the subcollection named after a UUID created by Firebase
i created this structure like this below.
func sendMessage(_ message: Message) {
    let document = db.collection("messages")
        .document(message.senderId)
        .collection(message.receiverId)
        .document()
    
    let messageData = ["fromId": message.senderId, 
   "toId": message.receiverId, "content":  message.content, 
   "timestamp": message.timestamp] as [String : Any]
    
    document.setData(messageData) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("ERROR SAVING MESSAGE INTO FIRESTORE \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }
    
    let recipientMessageDocument = db.collection("messages")
        .document(message.receiverId)
        .collection(message.senderId)
        .document()
    
    recipientMessageDocument.setData(messageData) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("ERROR SAVING MESSAGE INTO FIRESTORE \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }

and successfully fetch the messages like this:
func fetchMessages(_ fromId: String, _ toId: String) {
    db.collection("messages")
        .document(fromId)
        .collection(toId)
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("FAILED TO LISTEM FOR MESSAGES: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
                if change.type == .added {
                    let data = change.document.data()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
               let newMessage = ChatMessage(documentId: change.document.documentID, data: data)
                    self.messages.append(newMessage)
                    }
                }
            })
        }


but when i want to pull all the receiverId i circled below in the picture, i get "document does not exist" error. How can i get those receiverId s?
This is how i try to fetch the receiverIds. Actually this function is for getting userNames but at the beginning of the function i can't get content of the subcollection.
func addReceiverNamesToMessages(for userId: String) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    
    db.collection("messages")
        .document(userId)
        .getDocument { document, error in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                if let data = document.data() {
                    let receiverIds = Array(data.keys)
                    
                    for receiverId in receiverIds {
                        group.enter()
                        self.userProfileService.fetchUserProfile(uid: receiverId) { result in
                            switch result {
                            case .success(let profile):
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.chatUser.append(profile)
                                }
                            case .failure:
                                break
                            }
                            group.leave()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    group.notify(queue: .main) {
                        print("All profiles fetched")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }

My other question is about this is if that doc doesnt exist then how does this function works correctly? toId here is the receiverId in that subCollection
func fetchMessages(_ fromId: String, _ toId: String) {
    db.collection("messages")
        .document(fromId)
        .collection(toId)
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("FAILED TO LISTEM FOR MESSAGES: \ 
  (error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
                if change.type == .added {
                    let data = change.document.data()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let newMessage = ChatMessage(documentId: 
    change.document.documentID, data: data)
                        self.messages.append(newMessage)
                    }
                }
            })
        }


If the document ID is shown in italics, there is no actual document with that ID - and it's only shown in the console because there are subcollections under it. It will not show up in query results, which is also explained in the bottom right of the screenshot you shared. If you want to be able to load the parent documents, you'll have to ensure those documents actually exist.

None of the documents you show under "messages" exist.  You can tell because they are shown in italics, and the console is telling you the same in the lower right. As such, they will not show up in any queries on that collection using the iOS SDK.  You can still query the subcollections nested under these missing documents, but you must know the (missing) document ID and subcollection ID ahead of time to build a path to it.
See the documentation:

A document can exist even if one or more its ancestors don't exist.
For example, the document at path /mycoll/mydoc/mysubcoll/mysubdoc can
exist even if the ancestor document /mycoll/mydoc does not. The Cloud
Firestore data viewer displays non-existent ancestor document as
follows:

In a collection's list of documents, the document IDs of non-existent ancestor documents are italicized.
In a non-existent ancestor document's information panel, the data viewer points out that the document does not exist.


See also:

Firestore DB - documents shown in italics
Why are non auto-generated document Ids are in italics in Firestore console?


i see. My purpose was to fetch those non-exist receiverIds(actually firstly created by Firebase when creating users in Users Collection) and get their userProfile information like name imageUrl etc...those i circled are receiverId s and the left side of it the senderId s...so how can i fetch the Ids to which the user sent messages then?

As I said in my comment to your question too: you will need to ensure that those document exists if you want to read them. Also see the questions I linked, for other approaches.

Simply create empty documents in the place of the missing documents if you want something to query first to find the document IDs to build upon for the subcollection queries.
